# Iframe in Jquery isn't loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I was trying to experiment building an iframe with Jquery , which I think is straight forward through this code but it's not working ..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
              $("#opposition a").click(function(e) {
              var first_id  = $(this).attr('id');
              var second_id = $("h1").attr('id');
              $("#opposition img").mouseover(function() {
              $(this).css('border-width','5px');
        });
              $("#opposition img").mouseout(function() {
              $(this).css('border-width','2px');
        });
              $.get("compare_proc.php",{
              id:first_id,
             id2:second_id
    });
     $("#frame").attr("src", "http://www.google.com/");
              e.preventDefault();
                });
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="mydiv"><iframe id="frame" src="" width="100%" height="300">
   </iframe></div>
  <button id="button">Load</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of a header that Google.com is responding with called [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).  From the documentation:

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate
>   whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a
>   `<frame>` or `<iframe>`. Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks,
>   by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

not all servers send this response header for example ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UE65A/)), this works:

```
<div id="mydiv"><iframe id="frame" src="" width="100%" height="300">
   </iframe></div>
  <button id="button">Load</button>
<script>
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $("#frame").attr("src", "http://wikipedia.com");
});
</script>
```